# TypeScript: Type from the return values of an array of factory functions

Tags: typescript

My app has a number of factory functions that each return an object (more context at the bottom of this question). I'd like to create a type with the intersections of all of those returned objects.

```js
const factoryA = () => ({
  fun1(): string {
    return 'fun1';
  }
});
const factoryB = () => ({
  fun2(): number {
    return 2;
  }
});
const factoryList = [factoryA, factoryB];
```

The type I'd like to automatically create from `factoryList` would essentially be this:

```js
type FactoryListType = ReturnType<typeof factoryA> & ReturnType<typeof factoryB>
```

Is there a generic way to extract this type from `factoryList` without having to create it explicitly?

## Context

This is for a graphql server and the factories create DataLoaders for the current request. They are created in factories so the loader cache is cleared between requests.

For example:

```js
export const userLoaderFactory = () => ({
  user: new DataLoader<string, UserModel>((keys: string[]) => {
    return UserModel.query().whereIn('id', keys);
  })
});
```

Then, when the server creates the context for the request, it iterates over the list of factories, creates the data loaders, and adds them to the context:

```js
const createContext = () => {
  const loaders = loaderFactories.reduce((acc, factory) => {
    const factoryLoaders = factory();
    return {
      ...acc,
      ...factoryLoaders,
    };
  }, {});

  return {
    loaders
  };
};
```

I want to pass a Context type into my GraphQL types and resolvers that contain the loader type definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, this is what I've found.

```js
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;

const factoryList = [factoryA, factoryB];

export type FactoryListType = UnionToIntersection<
  ReturnType<typeof factoryList[number]>
>;
```

The `ReturnType<typeof factoryList[number]>>` creates a union between the return types for each factory. At first this seems good, but whenever you try to access a factory property, TypeScript complains that it "does not exist on type <Other Factory>".

Converting the union to an intersection seems to resolve this issue, but it does seem like a lot of extra work.

Comment: i think what you describe is better represented with a union (as you mentioned in your question). The behaviour of an error when accessing would be expected. you can always narrow union types by checking for a special property that all types have but is different on each one.

Comment: Can you explain why it's better represented as a union? As a union, it says the resulting object can contain this subset OR that subset of properties. However, the reality is that my code creates a combined object that contains ALL subsets in one object.

Comment: Ok, if that is what you want, i misinterpreted the question ("I'd like to create a type with the union of all of those returned objects.") - and you already have your solution. a union would be better if you always work with an object that is one of those factories in the list.

Comment: Ah, that was a typo on my part. Thank you for pointing that out.